# Scala trait linearization equivalent in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, multiple-inheritance

I'm migrating some Scala code to Kotlin, that uses method linearization in a hierarchy of clasess and interfaces (traits in Scala jargon).

Does Kotlin have something equivalent?
Any workaround?
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/trait-linearization-in-scala/

Here is a simple Scala example that uses linearization:

```
class old_Car 
{ 
    def method: String= "old car "
} 
  
// defining new_Car_Designs trait 
trait new_Car_Designs extends old_Car 
{ 
    override def method: String ="Designing-> "+ super.method 
} 
  
// defining new_Car_Part trait 
trait new_Car_Part extends old_Car 
{ 
    override def method: String = "Add new part-> "+ super.method 
} 
  
// defining new_Car_Paint trait 
trait new_Car_Paint extends old_Car 
{ 
    override def method: String = "Repainting-> "+ super.method 
} 
  
// defining new_Car class 
class new_Car extends new_Car_Paint with 
new_Car_Part with new_Car_Designs 
{ 
    override def method: String = "new car-> "+ super.method 
} 
  
// Creating object 
object geekforgeeks 
{ 
    // Main method 
    def main(args: Array[String]) 
    { 
        // new_Car object 
        var car1 = new new_Car 
        println(car1.method) 
    } 
}
```

Output:

```
new car-> Designing-> Add new part-> Repainting-> old car
```

Related info:

- https://dzone.com/articles/scala-vs-kotlin-multiple-inheritance-and-the-diamond-problem

Comment: Not really. The closest I can think of is [delegation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/delegation.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think this is possible in Kotlin by using language features. This is consistent with the language goals. Kotlin favors composition and delegation over inheritance and especially multi-inheritance.

But no matter which language we use, this problem can be solved with traditional OOP patterns - again: composition and delegation. Kotlin can help with this and the resulting code is very similar to the original Scala code. Conceptually, it works a little differently, relations between objects are more explicit, but at least for me personally this is even better, this is cleaner:

```kotlin
interface Car {
    val method: String
}

class OldCar : Car {
    override val method = "old car "
}

class OldCarDesigns(private val delegate: Car) : Car by delegate {
    override val method = "Designing-> " + delegate.method
}

class OldCarPart(private val delegate: Car) : Car by delegate {
    override val method = "Add new part-> " + delegate.method
}

class OldCarPaint(private val delegate: Car) : Car by delegate {
    override val method = "Repainting-> " + delegate.method
}

class NewCar private constructor(private val delegate: Car) : Car by delegate {
    constructor() : this(OldCarDesigns(OldCarPart(OldCarPaint(OldCar()))))

    override val method = "new car-> " + delegate.method
}

fun main() {
    val car = NewCar()
    println(car.method)
}
```

We don't necessarily need all these `Car by delegate` as we override the only member anyway, but if we have more members and would like to override them selectively, then this is helpful. Alternatively, we can introduce an abstract `DelegatingCar` which would do the delegation, but I think it doesn't add too much value.

Chain of cars: `OldCarDesigns(OldCarPart(OldCarPaint(OldCar())))` is ugly. If we like, we can create a helper function instead:

```kotlin
fun <T> T.linearize(vararg wrappers: (T) -> T) = wrappers.fold(this) { it, wrapper -> wrapper(it) }

constructor() : this(OldCar().linearize(::OldCarPaint, ::OldCarPart, ::OldCarDesigns))
```

Frankly speaking, `NewCar` doesn't feel very Kotlin-ish. In Kotlin, we usually avoid defining new types if their main/sole purpose is to create a graph of other objects. We prefer factory functions over new types.

BTW, ordering of your functions feels strange to me: new car -> designing -> adding part -> painting -> old car. Didn't you mean that the new car is based on a painted car, which in turn works on a car with added part, which works on redesigned car, which uses the old car as a base? It confused me a little when I was writing my answer ;-)

Comment: I've taken the example from an article in dzone.com.